# What are names of algebraic expressions? What is name of algebraic expressions having many terms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, terminology

Basically I have doubt about the use of word **polynomial=many terms**.

Sometimes books say ***algebraic expressions having many (or any number of)terms are polynomial***.
E.g 5/x is monomial expression.
5/x+ 7y is binomial expression

Then books say ***terms of polynomials can't have negative or fractional powers but terms of algebraic expressions can have***.
e.g. 5x is monomial but 5/x is not.

The above two things are confusing. **what is correct terminology for algebraic expressions having 1 term or 2 terms or many terms?**

Comment: You need to give examples of such books.  I know of no respectable book that says "algebraic expressions having many (or any number of)terms are polynomial".

Comment: If the powers are negative I personally wouldn't refer to them as monomials or binomials, especially when teaching pre-calculus level algebra. I would just call it a two-term expression. Later on students would be mature enough to accept modifications to the terminology considering the context, for example applying the binomial formula to $(5/x+\sqrt{x})^6$.

Comment: You may also want to know that if you allow negative but not fractional powers you get the rational functions. They are of interest in and of themselves. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function

Comment: @DavidP so (5/x +√x) is an algebraic expression and not binomial?

Comment: It is a binomial in the context that it is the sum of expressions that represent real numbers. You can take any binomial (polynomial) such as $3x^2-2y^3$ and set "let $x=e^p$ and let $y=\ln(z^2+1)$ and make that substitution; Does that invalidate the original expression as being a binomial? It's all how you look at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK there is no specific terminology for an algebraic expression having $1$ term or $2$ terms or many terms.  I'd just say "an algebraic expression having $\ldots$ terms."

"Many terms" for a polynomial is etymology, not definition.
A polynomial is not just any kind of algebraic expression: a polynomial in variable $x$ is a sum of one or more terms consisting of a coefficient (which does not depend on $x$) times a nonnegative integer power of $x$.

Comment: There are plenty of websites which uses word polynomial for algebraic expressions though they use non negative integer power for terms.(source - Google -Types of algebraic expressions) Should I avoid them or Is that a way to introduce algebraic expressions at elementary level?

Comment: I do agree with your answer but there are still some doubts. How do you see binomial expansion of (x+ 1/x)². Is (x+1/x) not a binomial? If not then why do books say binomial expansions of such expressions?

Comment: $x + 1/x$ is the result of substituting $y = 1/x$ in the polynomial $x + y$. The binomial theorem itself is about the binomial $x+y$, but you can substitute any valid expressions for $x$ and $y$ in the equation $(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^k y^{n-k}$ and get a true equation, even if it's not about a binomial.